# Array or hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Could anyone explain what is faster for reading, writing in Ruby: an `Array` or a `Hash`? And what are the usecases for `Array` and `Hash`?

```
Array.new
Hash.new
```

Comment: Its fully depends on what type of data You are handling.

Comment: Array and Hash are different animals and can't really be compared with a simple "Which is faster?"  Hash accesses run circles around Array accesses *until* you run into a key collision with the Hash. There are ways to handle that but basically Arrays don't care and Hashes do and than can negate the advantage. Arrays are great for queues and stacks and stink for searching. Hashes are great for random access and can act like miniature database tables but are not good choices for sequential tasks or handling key collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading and writing `Hash.new` is faster than `Array.new`. Watch this [`Why Hashes Will Be Faster in Ruby 2.0`](http://lanyrd.com/2012/goruco/swfqq/).

Comment: @LuísRamalho First time my copy got swapped in my editor. :) so pardon me on that.. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to store only some unique unordered values, please consider using `Set.new`. It's convenient hash based class with writing and reading in constant time.

Comment: If you expanded this to discuss the use-cases for `Hash` and `Array` this would make a good answer.

Comment: @thomasfedb The video I link,its awesome. Take some time and watch it. :)